# Avoiding dataloss in Go when writing with CLOSE_WAIT socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, go

1. start listening client with netcat -l
2. go program opens a conn with net.DialTCP to said client.
3. kill the netcat
4. in go program, do conn.Write() with a []byte ->  it runs fine without error!
5. it takes another conn.Write to get the error: broken pipe

The first write is the one where data loss happens, and I want to avoid.  if i only get an error I know i can just keep the data and try again later.
I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071574/2757887 which is a very similar case and the explanation seems to apply here, but it still doesn't explain how to deal with the issue, if the tcp protocol I need to implement only does one-way communication.

I've sniffed the traffic with wireshark, and when i kill the netcat, I can see that it sends FIN to the go program, to which the go program replies with ACK.  For some reason the go program doesn't immediately reply with it's own FIN - and i'm curious why that is, it might help with my problem - but there's probably a good reason for it.

Either way, from the "connection termination" section @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol, I conclude that the socket is in the CLOSE_WAIT state at this point, which I also confirmed with "netstat -np", which shows the socket going from ESTABLISHED to CLOSE_WAIT after killing netstat.

Looking at wireshark, the first conn.write results in a packet with push and ack fields set, and of course my payload. this is the write that succeeds fine in go.

then the old socket that used to belong to netstat sends RST,
which makes sure that as soon as i try to write in go (2nd write) it fails.

So my question is:

A) why can't I get an error on the first write? if the socket received the FIN and is in CLOSE_WAIT why does Go let me write to the socket and tell me all is fine?
B) is there any way I can check in Go whether the socket is in CLOSE_WAIT? and if so, I could for this purpose consider it closed and not do the write.

thanks,
Dieter

Comment: Are you reading from the socket ? Reading will tell you about netcat closing the socket. (Note that this is how the socket API works, regardless of which language you use the 2. write signals an error)

Comment: How will it tell me? I just tried it out - and remember, it's one way communication in the tcp protocol - my results:    

 * if i provide a byte array it just hangs (no one is writing the other end..)
 * if i provide an *empty* byte array, i get EOF both when the connection is established, as well as as in close_wait

Comment: You will get EOF. Ofcourse, you'll have to do the reading concurrently with performing the writes.

Comment: I don't understand how this solution should work. Like I said, both cases (established and close_wait) give an EOF, so how to tell the difference between these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, a successful `write` only tells you that data has been queued to be sent to the other end. If you need to make sure the other end gets that data, even if the connection closes or errors, you *must* store a copy of the data until the other end provides you with an application-level acknowledgment.

Comment: David, what you say is probably correct.  But like I explained, I must work within the constraints of a one-way application protocol.  
Again, if netstat can see that the socket is in close_wait, why can't my code?

Comment: @user2757887 You *can't* work within those constraints. You will always have a race condition. You need application-level acknowledgements.

Comment: *why* can't I? could you explain what the race condition is? it might not even apply in this scenario.. because my protocol is idempotent (there's no harm in sending the same data multiple times) and not-realtime, it's much safer to retry sending data later when the connection is established, instead of considering it processed when the socket is in closed_wait

Comment: @user2757887 Oh, then just resend the last few messages if a connection breaks. That's not perfect, but it's probably good enough.

Comment: @user2757887 The socket could be closed at any time. Your write() call could shove data out on the wire, and just before it reaches the other end, the receiver closes the socket, or catches fire. Or perhaps it receives the data, sends a TCP ack, and then catches fire before the TCP stack delivers the data to the receiving application.